# Slanted Stairs Structural Issue?

Tags: structural, stairs

First post, I'm interested in purchasing a house but the one hold up for me is a set of stairs going to the third floor of the house. They are noticeably slanted and I'm concerned that it could be a structural issue. The stairs seem to be held by the upper floor via a 1 or 2 inch steel pipe elbows and flanges. The only picture I have is from a previous inspection report that they proactively did when they put it up for sale. All the inspection report says is

> STAIRS
> Stairs are sloped at third floor recommend repair as desired using a licensed contractor.

Here is also the current owners reply:

[image: owners reply]

Anyway I'm interested in any information on how a contractor would go about fixing this, whether I should consult with a structural engineer for something like this, and how much would something like this cost?
[image: slanted stairs]
[image: under side of the stairs]

Comment: It is hard to see from a photo. Can you indicate in which direction the stairs are slanting?

Comment: They look like they slant downward as you move away from the left-hand wall.

Comment: Ya they slant downward as you move away from the wall as RETIREDATC had stated

Comment: what does the wall under the stairs look like?  is there storage under stairs? another set of stairs?  to fix you just jack up the wall the supports the side of the stairs that has settled.

Comment: Will depend on the cause of the slanting.  Somebody who built them was bad at measurements(cheaper) or the house is sliding/settling(expensive).

Comment: I would gut and rebuild a new set of stairs, not hard for an experienced contractor. We are not allowed to give prices here, it would be off-topic and unlikely to be accurate without knowing location and getting a better look at them in person.

Comment: I placed a new picture of under the steps from the listing. The house is apparently from 1844 according to the listing

Comment: Does it start (relatively) level and the top, and then progressively sag as you move toward the bottom? I think I see that, but it could be lens distortion. Assuming that it progressively sags, then does the bottom step run parallel to the house's floor in its neighborhood? The top stair obviously runs parallel to the floor at the top of the stairs.

Comment: That metal post could be intended to stabilize the hand rail.

Comment: Visual perception works by comparing parallel lines. You can actually feel the out-of-levelness when you walk on these stairs? Have you used a level? Because your mind assumes that certain stuff in the background is level and then measures from that baseline. That window's trim in the background behind the stairs, I think, is setting my perception.

Comment: You can actually feel the out of level Ness when you walk on the stairs

Comment: Thank you everyone for the input and answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an expert, but to me that certainly looks like settling. If so first step is to stop that, usually by installing laly columns (at least in my area).

Those can sometimes *slowly* be extended to lift the parts of the house which sank back to level, though you can expect some secondary damage like plaster cracking. Sometimes not, in which case you need to decide if it's something you can live with.

Some floors in the old part of my house have a difference of inches from one side of the house to the other, but it isn't going to move further (we think) and I can tolerate it, though I do have blocks under two pieces of furniture to bring them back to level.

Get someone to inspect the building. Possibly bring in a general contractor to tell you what can be done and guess at cost. Armed with those you can decide what you want to do -- pass on this house, or try to get the price dropped to reflect the money you'll immediately want to put into it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and input!